# PHP array_push dentro de función no actualiza array principal

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer un array_push desde mi función a un array que se encuentra fuera de la función. Necesito encontrar el id dentro del array y hacer un array_push en la posición indicada. El push sí se hace, pero el array principal no se actualiza. Podrían ayudarme por favor. Este es mi código, gracias:

```
$estructura = array(
    "Tipo"=>"Líder",
    "Nombre"=>"Jaime",
    "Empresarios"=>[
      ["Tipo"=>"Empresario", "Nombre"=>"Gloria", "id"=>"233", "invitados"=> [
          ["Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"María Juana", "id"=>"117", "invitados"=> []],
          ["Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"Mario López", "id"=>"230", "invitados"=> []]
        ]
      ],
      ["Tipo"=>"Empresario", "Nombre"=>"Andrés", "id"=>"28", "invitados"=> [
          ["Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"Camila", "id"=>"281", "invitados"=> [
              ["Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"Laura", "id"=>"57", "invitados"=> []],
              ["Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"Alex", "id"=>"84", "invitados"=> [
                  ["Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"Catalina", "id"=>"900", "invitados"=> []],
                  ["Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"Juan", "id"=>"700", "invitados"=> []]
                ]
              ],
              ["Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"Miguel", "id"=>"10", "invitados"=> []],
            ]
          ],
          ["Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"Omar", "id"=>"282", "invitados"=> []]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  );

$array = $estructura['Empresarios'];

function buscarId(&$array, $id) {

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value['id'] == $id) {
        $invitado = array("Tipo"=>"Invitado", "Nombre"=>"Gonzalo", "id"=>"91", "invitados"=> []);
        array_push($value['invitados'], $invitado);
        break;
    } else {
        if(count($value['invitados']) > 0) {
            $arr = $value['invitados'];
            buscarId($arr, $id);
        }
    }
}
return $array;
}

$test = buscarId($array, 700);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque en el `foreach` el `value` no actúa como referencia del array principal, puedes hacer 2 cosas:

Pasar `value` por referencia dentro del `foreach`:

```php
foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
    ...
        array_push($value['invitados'], $invitado);
    ...
}
```

O usar el `key` para acceder y modificar el array principal:

```php
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    ...
        array_push($array[$key]['invitados'], $invitado);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación. Me sirvió para resolverlo. Gracias.